# Вид связи между двумя предложениями

Tags: текстология

Пьер замечал, как после каждого попавшего ядра, после каждой потери все более и более разгоралось общее оживление.

Как из придвигающейся грозовой тучи, чаще и чаще, светлее и светлее вспыхивали на лицах всех этих людей (как бы в отпор совершающегося) молнии скрытого, разгорающегося огня.

Здесь параллельная связь? Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Связь, на мой взгляд, всё-таки цепная. Второе предложение присоединяется к первому  указательным местоимением ЭТИХ. Плюс употребление однокоренных слов - разгорающегося и разгоралось.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, здесь сочетание цепной и параллельной при преобладании параллельной. Чистой связи почти не бывает,тем более, что нужно рассматривать не 2, а 4-5 предложений для установления связи предложений в тексте.

Связь между этими предложениями основана на семантических соответствиях и ассоциациях. Указательное местоимение не связывает с предыдущим предложением, т.к. там нет речи о людях,только об общем оживлении. Общее оживление и разгорающийся огонь - слова одной семантической группы.И там, и там речь о процессе нарастания общего чувства. Наблюдается единство видо-временных форм: несов. вид глаголов прош.вр. Обратный порядок слов в обоих предложениях.Нет ни синонимов, ни союзов, ни наречий, ни местоимений, с чьей помощью второе предложение присоединялось бы к предыдущему.

Хотя есть однокоренные слова.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что  ЭТИ ДВА предложения  построены на параллельной связи, учитывая, что для нее характерно сопоставление, сравнение.

Нарастание напряжения битвы  сравнивается с усиливающейся и приближающейся грозой, а реальный огонь взрывающихся снарядов -  с огнем оживления на лицах людей.